# Откуда берется отступ

Tags: html, css

Собственно, откуда здесь отступ между картинками? Все уже убрал лишнее

http://where2smoke.ru/Chelyabinsk/testtest.html

Comment: покажите разметку и стили которые вы используете

Comment: ))) Ребят, да нет тут никаких стилей вообще, я все убрал подчистую. Только голый html

Comment: в общем проблема с тем что по умолчанию у тега img стоит `display:inline` - сейчас ищу вопрос чтобы закрыть как дубликат

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это особенность инлайновых элементов. Уберите переносы строк и пробелы между картинками или добавьте отрицательный `margin-left`, или используйте `float: left`.

Comment: Блин) Спасибо, теперь буду знать))

Comment: Можно также задать `font-size: 0;` для враппера, внутри которого находятся изображения.